# Count unique non-blank entries in a range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, unique, nonblank

I have data like this in Excel:

```
Person1    A    A    B    A         C    3
Person2                                  0
Person3    A    B    C    D    E    F    6
Person4              A    A    A         1
```

I am trying to find a formula that replicates the number in the last cell of each row, the number of unique elements associated with that person, excluding blanks. So for example Person1 has 3 since there is A, B, and C even though there are three A's. The number of columns is fixed / the same for everyone. The values A, B, C, etc, are strings (as opposed to numerics).

Can this be done using a formula?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:G1<>"")/COUNTIF(B1:G1,B1:G1&""))
```

Comment: @user51819 The numerator `(B1:G1<>"")` takes each cell and checks if it's blank, if it is blank it fails the check and gets counted as a 0, otherwise 1.  Then the denominator gets the total count of each element in the range.  The division then applies 1/Count for each element, such that if you have 3 of one element it becomes 1/3+1/3+1/3.  For example, on sample line 1, the breakdown is: 1/3+1/3+1/1+1/3+0/1+1/1 = 0.333+0.333+1+0.333+0+1 = 3

Comment: Really cool. Is there any risk of precision issues with this approach since it's working with fractions?

Comment: @user51819 There can be, but you can wrap the formula in `ROUND` if you run into any issues with that.

Comment: I prefer doing these with FREQUENCIES for that reason but COUNTIF does work surprisingly well :-)

Comment: FRQUENCY I mean

Comment: Plz see https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-in-a-range

Answer (score 4):

This is what I found:

`=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(B1:F1,B1:F1&""))`

It works quite interestingly:

[image: product]

It sums the results of the countifs, and it divides each one by 1.Thus, if you have the above example, it returns 4, because it sums:

**1/1 + 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/1 + 1/3 + 1/3**

Comment: I tested this and I don't think this gives the correct results on example row 3 and 4

Comment: @tigeravatar - yup, my test used to be a bit fake... I had 3 times `A` and I was expecting 3, thus I considered it working.

Comment: Hmm... now it gives a #DIV/0! error if there are any blank cells in the row

Comment: @tigeravatar - slowly getting there :) I knew there was something with `1/`.

Answer (score 3):

An UDF to use in sheet

```
Public Function GetUniqueCount(ByVal rng As Range) As Long
    Dim dict As Object, currCell As Range
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each currCell In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(currCell) Then dict(currCell.Value) = 1
    Next currCell
    GetUniqueCount = dict.Count
End Function
```

---

In sheet use:

[image: Sheet]